# How to run jupyter notebook in the background ? No need to keep one terminal for it

Tags: jupyter-notebook

Often we run `jupyter notebook` to pop up a page in browser to use notebook. However, the terminal opening the server remains there. Is there a way that we can close that terminal with server running in the back ?

Answer (score 76, accepted):

You can put the process into the background by using `jupyter notebook --no-browser & disown`. You can close the terminal afterwards and the process will still be running.

If you're using `zsh` you can also use a shorter version that does the same: `jupyter notebook --no-browser &!`.

To kill the process you can use `pgrep jupyter` to find the PID of the process and then `kill 1234`, replacing 1234 with the PID you just found.

#### Explanation

The `--no-browser` flag makes jupyter not open the browser automatically, it also works without this flag.

The `&` puts it into the background of the currently running shell.

The `disown` then removes the job from the background of the currently running shell and makes it run independently of the shell so that you may close it.

In the `zsh` version the `&!` is a built-in function that does the same as `& disown`.

Comment: Can you please
 give an example?

Comment: @omehoque & means `unix run task in background with no logs in tty`

Comment: How to close it after?

Comment: @PabloRuizRuiz `ps aux | grep jupyter` and `kill 1234`?

Comment: Using this method, closing the terminal shuts down jupyter server for me. Any reasons as to why this might be happening?

Comment: This does not work, and the answer lacks details. Closing Jupyter closes the task.

Comment: @PabloRuizRuiz `jupyter notebook stop`

Comment: This just does not work for me. It prints a cryptic `[5] 696760`, gives me a moment where it looks like it works, and then prints the same `jupyterlab | extension was successfully linked.` etc. and hogs the terminal.

Comment: Not sure why the answer hasn't been edited yet. The full command to run is `jupyter notebook --no-browser & disown` no-browser to run without opening a browser. & to put it in the background. disown to detach it from the terminal. You can quit using the quit button on the webpage, or by killing the process using its pid.

Comment: kill 1234 is not working for me, I have to use kill -9 1234

Comment: @pgrosslicht I am using the zsh shell. I tried both `jupyter lab & disown` and `jupyter lab &!`. Unfortunately Jupyter in the web browser says, "Kernel Restarting:
The kernel for […] appears to have died. It will restart automatically."

Comment: What about in windows?

Answer (score 50):

#### Tmux is a good option available to run your Jupyter Notebook in the background.

I am running my Jupyter Notebook on a google cloud platform's VM instance with OS: Ubuntu 16.0. Where

1. I have to start SSH terminal
2. Then run the command: `jupyter-notebook --no-browser --port=5000`. It will start the Jupyter Notebook on port number 5000 on that VM instance
3. Then I open my browser and typer ip_addrees_of_my_instance:port_number which is 5000. It will open my Notebook in the browser.

Now up to this, all is good. But wait if the connection with my SSH terminal is terminated then the Jupyter Notebook stops immediately and hence I have to re-run it once again once the ssh terminal is restarted or from new ssh terminal.

To avoid this `tmux` is very good option.

#### Terminal Multiplexer (`tmux`) to Keep SSH Sessions Running in the background after ssh terminal is closed:

1. Start the ssh terminal
2. Type `tmux`. It will open a window in the same terminal.
3. Give command to start Jupyter Notebook here. Open Notebook.

Now if SSH terminal is closed/terminated it will keep running your notebook on the instance.

If the connection terminated then:

4. reconnect or open new ssh terminal. To see this Jupyter Server(which is kept running in the background) type: `tmux attach` command.

(Edited: changed "notebook" to "Jupyter Server")

Want to terminate tmux session:

5. Close the notebook. Then type `exit` in tmux-terminal-window.
   (update: If we close the notebook and use `tmux detach` command: it will exit from tmux session window/terminal without terminating/stopping the tmux sessions)

For more details please refer to this article: https://www.tecmint.com/keep-remote-ssh-sessions-running-after-disconnection/

Comment: When I run the code `jupyter notebook notebook.ipynb` in the tmux terminal, it does give the link to run the notebook in the browser. But browser displays the following message: "This site can’t be reached
localhost refused to connect."

Comment: try this: close tmux session (detach tmux), then restart the server and try once again in a new tmux terminal to run this command. let me know if you face the same problem once again.

Comment: @Yogesh From the answer what I understand is after reconnecting "tmux attach" will open the running notebook automatically. After attaching, I can see the notebook is running but it doesn't open on the browser. What am I missing?

Comment: Hi Shaurov, the command after running this command: "tmux attach" from the terminal it will show Jupyer Server is running. To see the running notebook you need to open the Jupyter notebook in the Browser. ( I have edited the text from "Notebook" to "Jupyter Notebook". Thanks )

Comment: How does one see the output from this? Does it get logged each couple of minutes on the file? 

I can see that the file is still running but not sure where the outputs are

Comment: @YogeshAwdhutGadade I tried running tmux in Terminal on a Mac. It said, `zsh: command not found: tmux`. I guess I will need to install tmux?

Comment: @BrianSchack Yes, it seems that the tmux command is not found on your Mac, which indicates that it is not currently installed. To use tmux, you will need to install it on your machine. You can install tmux on your Mac by using a package manager like Homebrew.

Comment: @Kurt Sorry for the very delayed response. I am answering so that others can benefit if they face the same issue:

In tmux, you can view the output from a running program by attaching to the session. Use the command tmux attach-session -t <session_name> to connect and see the program's output in real-time. If the output is logged to a file, you can access it using a text editor or command-line tools like less or tail. Tmux does not log output by default, but you can redirect it to a file when starting the program. Remember to detach from the session with Ctrl+b followed by d.

Answer (score 29):

Under *nix, the best way to run a program avoiding to be terminated by closing the terminal is to use *nohup* (no Hang up).

To start browser after running the server use the command:

```
nohup jupyter notebook &
```

And to start the server without opening the browser use the command:

```
nohup jupyter notebook --no-browser &
```

Note that you can shut down the `jupyter` server by using Quit in the upper right of the page of `jupyter`.

`nohup` puts as a parent of the process init(0), so it will not receive the "Hang Up" signal when the terminal is closed. All the output (standard output and standard error) are redirected to the file `nohup.out`
`nohup` exists both as program and shell command, so if you have `bash`, check `man` page of `bash` to read more details.

Comment: Can confirm it works on Windows Subsystem for Linux (tested on Ubuntu 18.04 and Windows 10 1803)

Comment: This is the real best answer for the *nix systems. It works great

Comment: Since I need the URL with port and token from this executed on remote server, I wrap this command like so: `nohup bash -c 'jupyter lab --no-browser' &> server.out &` and get the url to paste in my local machine's web browser: `cat server.out`

Answer (score 23):

This works for me when running a jupyter notebook server in the background.

`$> nohup jupyter notebook --allow-root > error.log &`

Stop the nohup jupyter notebook is simple.

First, find the pid of jupyter:

`$> ps -ef| grep jupyter`

e.g output like:

`root     11417  2897 2 16:00 pts/0 00:04:29 /path/to/jupyter-notebook`

Then kill the process:

`$> kill -9 11417`

You can also simplify this by storing the pid with:

`$> nohup jupyter notebook --allow-root > error.log & echo $!> pid.txt`

i.e, you can stop the notebook with:

`$> kill -9 $(cat pid.txt)`

---

An alternative way to stop the jupyter notebook is quit from the notebook page.

Comment: do not use `kill -9` by default, it's too harsh.

Comment: `jupyter notebook` has `list` and `stop` subcommands.
If you've launched only one server you can just `jupyter notebook stop` instad of `ps aux | grep && kill`. It also stops notebook gracefully.

Comment: @Adrian what do you mean by "too harsh?" In my experience other kill commands don't always get the job done.

Comment: Is there a way to send a running command to background without having to stop and restart it to add the nohup and &

Answer (score 7):

You can use `screen` to run it.

```
screen -A -m -d -S anyscreenname jupyter notebook --no-browser
```

This will start jupyter in a screen and you can access screen using screen commands.

Answer (score 6):

Actually, `jupyter notebook &` alone is not enough, the backend will still log to your screen. 
What you need is, cited from this [issue](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/74520/can-i-redirect-output-to-a-log-file-and-background-a-process-at-the-same-time)

```
jupyter notebook > /path/to/somefileforlogging 2>&1 &
```

Answer (score 3):

You can start up the notebook in a `screen` or `tmux` session. Makes it easy to check error messages, etc.

Answer (score 2):

For remote machines `jupyter notebook &` works fine.
However, it does not work on local machines when you close the terminal.
For local machines use `tmux`.

Comment: This doesn't work when I try executing on RHEL remote machine. The URL with token it returns to stout doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

```
jupyter notebook & >> disown
```

put the process into the background by using `jupyter notebook &`
then type `disown` or `disown <the process id>`
you can close the terminal now

Answer (score 1):

Not real sophisticated but it gets the job done:

```
#! /bin/bash

#probably should change this to a case switch

if [ "$1" == "end" ]
    then
        echo
        echo "Shutting Down jupyter-notebook"
        killall jupyter-notebook
        echo
      exit 0
 fi

if [ "$1" == "-h" ]
   then
        echo   
        echo "To start  : jnote <port> [default 8888]" 
        echo "To end    : jnote end"
        echo "This help : jnote -h"
        echo
      exit 0
 fi

#cast from string
PORT=$(($1))

RETURN=0
PID=0

if [ "$PORT" == "0" ] || [ "$PORT" == "" ]; then PORT=8888; fi

echo
echo "Starting jupyter-notebook"

#background and headless, set port, allow colab access, capture log, don't open browser yet

nohup jupyter notebook \
 --NotebookApp.allow_origin='https://colab.research.google.com' \
 --port=$PORT --NotebookApp.port_retries=0 \
 --no-browser >~/jnote.log 2>&1 &

RETURN=$?
PID=$!

#Wait for bg process to complete - add as needed
sleep 2

if [ $RETURN == 0 ]
   then
        echo
        echo "Jupyter started on port $PORT and pid $PID"
        echo "Goto `cat ~/jnote.log | grep localhost: | grep -v NotebookApp`"
        echo
      exit 0
   else
        echo 
        echo "Jupyter failed to start on port $PORT and pid $PID with return code $RETURN"
        echo "see ~/jnote.log"
        echo
      exit $RETURN
 fi
```

Answer (score 1):

Detach Jupyter process from the controlling terminal and send all its input and output data to `/dev/null` which is a special device file that writes-off any data written to it.

```
jupyter notebook </dev/null &>/dev/null &
```

Lazy people like me would prefer to edit `~/.bash_aliases` and create an alias:

```
alias jnote='jupyter notebook </dev/null &>/dev/null &'
```

Reference: https://www.tecmint.com/run-linux-command-process-in-background-detach-process/

Answer (score 0):

Here is a command that launches jupyter in background (`&`) detached from the terminal process (`disown`) and without opening the browser (`--no-browser`)
No log will be shown on the terminal since they are redirected (`&>`) to a file `jupyter_server.log` so they can still be referred to later.

`jupyter notebook --no-browser &> jupyter_server.log & disown`

If you don't wan't to store the logs(discouraged):

`jupyter notebook --no-browser &> /dev/null & disown`

Thanks to the other answers this one is built upon: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55453977/3581903) and [there](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47331417/3581903)

Comment: This answer has already been given

Comment: Which one ? I could'nt find one matching all the criteria I detailed

Answer (score 0):

I creating shortcut on my ipad and in my case best it’s using screen

```
screen -d -m jupyter lab --no-browser --port=8888
```

Comment: There are **14 existing answers** to this question, including a top-voted, accepted answer with over **sixty votes**. Are you _certain_ your solution hasn't already been given? If not, why do you believe your approach improves upon the existing proposals, which have been validated by the community? Offering an explanation is _always_ useful on Stack Overflow, but it's _especially_ important where the question has been resolved to the satisfaction of both the OP and the community. Help readers out by explaining what your answer does different and when it might be preferred.

Answer (score 0):

You can set Jupyter Notebook / Lab as a systemd service.

Create a wrapper that runs Jupyter Lab, call it `start-jupyter-lab`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
python -Xfrozen_modules=off -m jupyter lab --no-browser --port=8888 --notebook-dir=[START_DIR]
```

Make it executable with `chmod +x start-jupyter-lab`.

Then create a systemd unit file `$HOME/.config/systemd/user/jupyterlab.service`:

```
[Unit]
Description=Jupyter Lab
After=network.target
StartLimitIntervalSec=5
StartLimitBurst=0

[Service]
Type=simple
Restart=always
RestartSec=1
ExecStart=[FULL_PATH_TO_WRAPPER]/start-jupyter-lab

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Reload systemd units with `systemctl --user daemon-reload`.

You can now start the server with `systemctl --user start jupyterlab` and open your browser to `localhost:8888`.

You can stop the server with `systemctl --user stop jupyterlab`.

You can set it up to start it automatically on system boot with `systemctl --user enable jupyterlab` (user `disable` to undo that).

Answer (score -1):

As suggested by one of the users, using
`jupyter notebook &`
solves the issue. Regarding the comments stating that it kills the kernel after closing the terminal, probably you are using
`jupyter-notebook &`.

Comment: `&` just puts the process in background, meaning you can use the terminal after starting it (it doesn't switch to the subshell created by the process). But the process is still a child of that shell, so closing the shell will kill the jupyter kernel too. What detach the process from the current shell is `disown`

Answer (score -1):

If you are using iTerm2 software,
first you need to set:

```
brew shellenv
```

Then start jupyter in nohup:

```
eval $(/usr/local/bin/brew shellenv)

nohup jupyter notebook &
```