# Running IPython notebook in the background using tmux

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, tmux

I am trying to run a IPython notebook in the background using `tmux`. For it, I am following this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47331050/how-to-run-jupyter-notebook-in-the-background-no-need-to-keep-one-terminal-f) in stackoverflow. In the `tmux` terminal, When I run the code `jupyter notebook notebook.ipynb`, it does give the link to run the notebook in the browser.

But browser displays the following message: "This site can’t be reached
localhost refused to connect."

How can I solve the issue?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're running this on a remote server. You just have to edit the link : replace the word `localhost` with ip address of the remote server.

`hostname -i` returns ip address on ubuntu machine for instance.