# Failed to use screen or nohup to keep Jupyter Notebook running in the background

Tags: python, server, jupyter-notebook

I am doing machine learning on the company's server

I usually start the Jupyter notebook on my laptop, using the command `jupyter-notebook --ip=192.168.1.200 --no-browser --port=999` in Xshell command line. Then copy the URL link to a browser.

This time the ML is going to take up a lot of time, so I wish to run the training over the weekend.

How can I achieve it as I turned off my laptop and take it home and reopen the same Jupyter page on Monday?

I have tried

1. nohup

`nohup jupyter-notebook --ip=192.168.1.200 --no-browser --port=999 -> jupyter.out &`

and `nohup jupyter-notebook --ip=192.168.1.200 --no-browser --port=999 > jupyter.out 2>&1`

But this popped me `nohup: ignoring input and redirecting stderr to stdout`

2. Screen

I also tried as `screen` as mentioned in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45835971/persistent-use-of-jupyter-notebook-from-remote-server)

By typing `screen` to enter a screen and start the Jupyter Notebook there using the URL provided (localhost:999 in the browser does not work for me).

While I started the training and closed the browser then reopen the Jupyter Notebook in the browser, the training stopped once I turned off the browser. The epoch stopped at 9.

By the way, it is a Linux server built using Centos.

Thanks

Comment: This might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47331050/how-to-run-jupyter-notebook-in-the-background-no-need-to-keep-one-terminal-for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well.. I can be done by typing `screen` in the server command line and run jupyter notebook in the screen.